# Не могу установить соединение с распбери

Tags: windows, powershell

На днях прикупил себе Raspberry pi 2, поставил на неё Windows IoT, но для работы с этой ОС нужно ей удалённо управлять, а для этого нужно установить соединение с ней через PowerShell. Всё я делал по [инструкции](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm), но на третей команде `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <machine-name or IP Address> -Credential <machine-name or IP Address or localhost>\Administrator` у меня PowerShell плюётся ошибками. Я не понимаю что делать, помогите. 
Вот всё что я делал с Шеллом:

```
Windows PowerShell
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2015. Все права защищены.

PS C:\Windows\system32> net start WinRMnet start WinRM
Синтаксис данной команды:

NET START
[service]

PS C:\Windows\system32> net start WinRM
Служба "Служба удаленного управления Windows (WS-Management)" запускается.
Служба "Служба удаленного управления Windows (WS-Management)" успешно запущена.

PS C:\Windows\system32>  Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 192.168.0.100

Настройка безопасности службы WinRM.
Данная команда изменяет список TrustedHosts для клиента WinRM. Возможно, не будет проверяться подлинность компьютеров,
указанных в списке TrustedHosts. Также возможно, что клиенты будут отправлять на эти компьютеры учетные данные. Вы
действительно хотите изменить этот список?
[Y] Да - Y  [N] Нет - N  [S] Приостановить - S  [?] Справка (значением по умолчанию является "Y"): Y
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.100 -Credential localhost\Administrator
Enter-PSSession : Сбой подключения к удаленному серверу 192.168.0.100. Сообщение об ошибке: Отказано в доступе. Подробн
ости см. в разделе справки "about_Remote_Troubleshooting".
строка:1 знак:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.100 -Credential localhost\Adm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (192.168.0.100:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.100 -Credential 192.168.0.100\Administrator
Enter-PSSession : Сбой подключения к удаленному серверу 192.168.0.100. Сообщение об ошибке: Отказано в доступе. Подробн
ости см. в разделе справки "about_Remote_Troubleshooting".
строка:1 знак:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.100 -Credential 192.168.0.100 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (192.168.0.100:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: А если не подставлять имя хоста?

`Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.0.100 -Credential Administrator`

Answer (score 1):

Открыть в Браузере http://192.168.0.100:8080 и ввести логин и пароль. Затем такие же ввести в PowerShell.